# Cant find the folder where the build is being generated

Tags: angular7, ng-build

E:\Project1\gui> ng build --configuration=staging --output-path=\"artifacts\"

```
staging": {   "fileReplacements": [  
        {  
            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",  
            "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"  
        }
    ]
}
```

Can someone please tell me where the build is being created when I run the above line?